# How to get info on a router-attached device other then IP and MAC?

Tags: mac, router, ip

My router shows a connected device (IP, MAC address), and I would like to find more info about it since I do not recognize the device. How can I do that?

I am working on a Windows box.

Comment: Turn the router off and wait for complaints.

Comment: @DavidPostill wow, dumb and dumber

Comment: Wow. It took you 4 months to come up with that response? :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking up the MAC address in a database like http://aruljohn.com/mac.pl to see the vendor, this could narrow down the device.

Or blacklist the MAC address so it can't get an IP address, or give it a static DHCP IP assignment that isn't valid and see who complains their device doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Next to @acejavelin 's answer, there are various portmapping tools, capable to identify the background service.

Many times, the a device has a HTTP or SMTP or SSH port, these services are also capable to say their software version (and thus, also the hardware version).